# How To Add Multiple Cards Of The Same CardView To A RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android

Here is a video of what I trying to do and explanation of the issue that I am having. Go to the following link below.

https://file.re/2021/09/12/2021-09-1210-43-21/

Here is the XML, Java, and Manifest Code Video. Go to the following link below.

https://file.re/2021/09/12/2021-09-1211-32-13/

Answer worked, but now I have two new problems. Here is the video link below.

https://file.re/2021/09/12/2021-09-1212-08-04/

I am creating an app that lists `CardView` layouts to a `RecyclerView`.

My app will add the `CardView` layout to the `RecyclerView` list, but it only lists one. I want it to add multiples of the same CardView when the user clicks on the button to add the card (basically cloning the `CardView` layout one under the other).

Here is what I have in my Button Click...

```
ftocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();
                    addFahToCelCard.add(new RecyclerItem());
                    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_view);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                    recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addFahToCelCard);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerItemAdapter);
                }
            }
        });
```

I've tried putting the `ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();` under the MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity class just before the onCreate like this...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final private ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();
```

That didn't work.

If I don't keep `ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();` in the button click listener, and I add a new CardView it will add a new one behind the original one each time the button is clicked, and if I delete the card it keep popping back up until I delete them all off. How do I fix this the way I want it to behave? I hope this all makes sense.

I appreciate the help!

Here is everything in the java class..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addFahToCelCard;

    private Animation fromBottom;
    private Animation toBottom;
    private Boolean clicked = false;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerItemAdapter recyclerItemAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public FloatingActionButton mainConverterMenuFloatBtn;
    public TextView chooseConverterLabel, ftocConverterLabelBtn, ftokConverterLabelBtn, ctofConverterLabelBtn, ctokConverterLabelBtn, ktofConverterLabelBtn, ktocConverterLabelBtn;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        fromBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.from_bottom_animation);
        toBottom = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.to_bottom_animation);

        mainConverterMenuFloatBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_temp_converter_float_btn);
        chooseConverterLabel = findViewById(R.id.choose_converter_label);
        ftocConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_f_to_c_converter_label_btn);
        ftokConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_f_to_k_converter_label_btn);
        ctofConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_c_to_f_converter_label_btn);
        ctokConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_c_to_k_converter_label_btn);
        ktofConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_k_to_f_converter_label_btn);
        ktocConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_k_to_c_converter_label_btn);

        addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addFahToCelCard);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerItemAdapter);

        mainConverterMenuFloatBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mainConverterMenu();
            }
        });

        ftocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    addFahToCelCard.add(new RecyclerItem());
                    recyclerItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ftokConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ctofConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ctokConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ktofConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ktocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private void addFahToCelCard() {

    }

    private void mainConverterMenu() {
        setVisibility(clicked);
        setClickable(clicked);
        setAnimation(clicked);
        clicked = !clicked;
    }

    private void setVisibility(Boolean clicked) {

        if (!clicked) {
            chooseConverterLabel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ftocConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ftokConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ctofConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ctokConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ktofConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ktocConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            chooseConverterLabel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ftocConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ftokConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ctofConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ctokConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ktofConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ktocConverterLabelBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    }

    private void setClickable(Boolean clicked) {

        if (!clicked) {
            chooseConverterLabel.setClickable(true);
            ftocConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(true);
            ftokConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(true);
            ctofConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(true);
            ctokConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(true);
            ktofConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(true);
            ktocConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(true);
        } else {
            chooseConverterLabel.setClickable(false);
            ftocConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(false);
            ftokConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(false);
            ctofConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(false);
            ctokConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(false);
            ktofConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(false);
            ktocConverterLabelBtn.setClickable(false);
        }

    }

    private void setAnimation(Boolean clicked) {

        if (!clicked) {
            chooseConverterLabel.startAnimation(fromBottom);
            ftocConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
            ftokConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
            ctofConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
            ctokConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
            ktofConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
            ktocConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(fromBottom);
        } else {
            chooseConverterLabel.startAnimation(toBottom);
            ftocConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
            ftokConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
            ctofConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
            ctokConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
            ktofConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
            ktocConverterLabelBtn.startAnimation(toBottom);
        }
    }

    private void closeActionButton() {
        setVisibility(clicked);
        setClickable(clicked);
        setAnimation(clicked);
        clicked = !clicked;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.show_hide_float_convert_btn) {

            if (mainConverterMenuFloatBtn.isShown()) {
                mainConverterMenuFloatBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_visibility_off_32);
            } else if (!mainConverterMenuFloatBtn.isShown()) {
                mainConverterMenuFloatBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_visibility_32);
            }

        } else if (id == R.id.app_help) {

        } else if (id == R.id.tip_developer) {

        } else if (id == R.id.premium_features) {

        } else if (id == R.id.about_app) {

        } else if (id == R.id.exit_app) {

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class RecyclerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerItemAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

        public ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerItemList;
        public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener recyclerItemListener;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick (int position);
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            recyclerItemListener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener;
        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView fahtoCelResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;
            
            public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert);
                fahtoCelResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftc);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        public RecyclerItemAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> rList) {
            recyclerItemList = rList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_celsius_converter_layout, parent, false);
            RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
            return recyclerViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            RecyclerItem currentItem = recyclerItemList.get(position);
            final String[] result = new String[1];

            holder.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String getIputFahValue = holder.inputFahValueET.getText().toString();
                    NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
                    if(!getIputFahValue.isEmpty()) {
                        double d = Double.parseDouble(getIputFahValue);
                        double dd = d - 32;
                        double ddd = dd * 5;
                        double dddd = ddd / 9;
                        result[0] = Double.toString(dddd);

                        holder.fahtoCelResult.setText(nf.format(dddd) + "°C");
                        holder.fahtoCelResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.shortResult = nf.format(dddd) + "°C";
                        holder.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + nf.format(dddd) + "°C";

                        if (result[0].contains(".0")) {
                            result[0] = result[0].replace(".0", "");
                            holder.fahtoCelResult.setText(result[0] + "°C");
                            holder.fahtoCelResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.shortResult = result[0] + "°C";
                            holder.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + result[0] + "°C";
                        }else if (result[0].contains(".000")) {
                            result[0] = result[0].replace(".000", "");
                            holder.fahtoCelResult.setText(result[0] + "°C");
                            holder.fahtoCelResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.shortResult = result[0] + "°C";
                            holder.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + result[0] + "°C";
                        }

                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Fahrenheit Value Field Cannot Be Blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

            holder.fahtoCelResult.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                    adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_file_copy_32);
                    adb.setTitle("Copy Result");
                    adb.setMessage("You can copy the result to your clipboard if you would like. Choose if you want the short or long result copied to your clipboard.\n\nExample of Short and Long Result:\nShort Result: 32°C\nLong Result: 0°F is 32°C");

                    adb.setPositiveButton("Short", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", holder.shortResult);
                            cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Result Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    adb.setNegativeButton("Long", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", holder.longResult);
                            cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Result Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                    adb.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}});

                    adb.create();
                    adb.show();

                    return false;
                }
            });

            holder.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    recyclerItemList.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                }
            });


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return recyclerItemList.size();
        }
    }

    public class RecyclerItem {

        public RecyclerItem() {

        }

    }
}
```

The recyclerView should be listing the CardViews and also allowing duplicates.

Comment: about the exception problem that raises when you delete some items, try to use `holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()`, instead of `getAdapterPosition` or the old final position value.

Comment: whenever you use a value inside a listener I guess it takes the value that exists right now and hold it as final, so if you have 5 items and deleted the first 3, the last two will still have their position stored as 4 and 5 instead of 1 and 2, thats why you should call the holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition() to get the current position instead of the final stored one, that way he stores the holder as final instead of storing a const int value

Comment: You sir are a genius! Thank you so much! Everything is working now! Thank you all soooooo very much!!!

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175887/how-do-i-add-multiple-cardview-layouts-to-a-recyclerview?noredirect=1#comment122264525_69175887

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think you are just using the `RecyclerView` the wrong way.

In your code snippet, you are initializing the `RecyclerView` as well as the adapter and all other components every time the user clicks the button.

First of all you will have to create the insert method in the `RecyclerItemAdapter` class.

### RecyclerItemAdapter.java

```java
class RecyclerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<RecyclerItem> items;

        RecyclerItemAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerItems) {
            this.items = recyclerItems;
        }

        //...


        public void addItem(RecyclerItem item) {
            items.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Then, you have ton initialize the `RecyclerView` only once. The best place to do that is in the `onCreate` method.

### MainActivity.java

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addFahToCelCard;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();
        setupRecyclerView();
        setupClickListener();
    }

    private void setupRecyclerView() {
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_view);
        recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addFahToCelCard);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerItemAdapter);
    }
}
```

Now add your `onClickListener` which will only add the card to the list.

```java
private void setupClickListener() {
        ftocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                recyclerItemAdapter.addItem(new RecyclerItem());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is still not giving me the behavior I am wanting.

Answer (score 1):

What is your xml layout for this cardview ? It looks like this cardview is in another layout that has match parent as width and height.
If thats the case items are too big to show.

---

Okay so try making first reletive layout height = 100dp to match the card view in fahrenheit_to_celsius_converter_layout.xml

Comment: It does list the CardView. After I add the first one, and when I go to add another one and then another one it keeps adding behind the first CardView. So, it's stacking behind each other instead of listing below each other.

Comment: I know i've seen your vid, but if it is like i said it will always show only the first one

Comment: Ok. I'll update my question with the XML that you asked for. One sec...

Comment: I'll have to add another video displaying the XML because my question has reached it's character limit.

Comment: maybe try here as a comment ?

Comment: There you go video added.

Comment: Your answer worked, but it created two additional problems. I updated my question with a new video.

Comment: Ok I figured out the first problem. You told me to change the width of the first RelativeLayout to 360dp and the height to 100dp. When I put the match_parent back for the width and kept height at 100dp it fixed it. So, it's centered now, and also listing them like I want. Now, I just need to figure out the second problem with removing cards from the RecyclerView. I still get that crash after I removed a few of them off. I really appreciate your and everyone's help with this. Thank you so much!

Comment: I would guess that the second problem is caused by index out of reach or smth. 
U can check what causes a crash in run log

Answer (score 0):

well I didn't understand the problem very well but from what I understood here's what you should do :

- first you shouldn't be creating a new recycler view on every button click, instead you should put the code that initializes the recycler view in onCreate method that exist in the activity class and just keep a reference to the arraylist that holds the data and the adapter as global variables.
- whenever the user clicks the button you should add a new item to the arraylist of data and use adapter.notifyDataItemSetChanged to tell the recycle view to check if there's any change happened to the recycle view and take action if necessary

here's a part of code that explains what I'm saying and I hope you that even if that doesn't answer your question, you catch a glimpse of how to deal with recyclerview :

first as I said you should keep a reference to the arraylist that holds the data and the adapter as global variables so put those outside any method in the activity

```
RecyclerItemAdapter recyclerItemAdapter ; 
ArrayList <RecyclerItem>addFahToCelCard ;
```

and then put this code instead of the button code

```
    addFahToCelCard = new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_view);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addFahToCelCard);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerItemAdapter);
    ftocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            addFahToCelCard.add(new RecyclerItem());
            recyclerItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
});
```

that way whenever you want to edit the recyclerView data anytime you can add/remove items from the global arraylist and notify the adapter just like the code inside the button OnClickListener

---

### **update to the last video posted about the exception**

this problem raises when you delete some items, try to use holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition(), instead of getAdapterPosition or the old final position value.

whenever you use a value inside a listener I guess it takes the value that exists right now and hold it as final, so if you have 5 items and deleted the first 3, the last two will still have their position stored as 4 and 5 instead of 1 and 2, thats why you should call the `holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` to get the current position instead of the final stored one, that way he stores the holder as final instead of storing a const int value.

Comment: Thanks, but your answer is still not giving me the behavior I am wanting.

Comment: then explain more, as I said I didn't understand the flow of your application

Comment: + your naming convention of buttons is very confusing I can't differentiate between them as they look all the same but differ in one or two letters {ftoc-ftok-ctof-ctok-ktoc-ktof}, that will probably cause you troubles in debugging your application later

Comment: yes I saw your code but can you just write the flow of your application in bulleted manner (1-if the user does something, 2- the application should do the following/ 1- if the user clicked a button, 2- the following should happen), that might help me or hamza above help you more and achieve what you are exactly wishing to do

Comment: Thanks anyways, I will redesign my app without the use of RecyclerView. I'm not that great with listing. Besides getting the app to list everything properly, everything else works perfectly.

Comment: well it's your loss then, recycler view is a very important component in any mobile application that it shouldn't be ignored or not used. I hope you rethink your decision and not give up easily. Good luck

Comment: Ok, give me a few minutes. I will explain everything in a video, and I will add the video to my question.

Comment: Ok there you go. I have updated my question. The video link is at the beginning of my question.

Comment: Hopefully the video explains everything for you.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this one too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69175887/how-do-i-add-multiple-cardview-layouts-to-a-recyclerview?noredirect=1#comment122264525_69175887