# How Do I Add Multiple CardView Layouts To A RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Here is a video of the behavior of the app that I am trying to explain just in case if you didn't understand my explanation of the problem. See the link below...

https://file.re/2021/09/14/2021-09-1405-16-22/

I am trying to develop an android app that has several card view layouts that will be displayed in one recycler view. I am not having much luck getting the recycler view to list the layouts like I want it to. I can add the first layout just fine, and then add the second layout just as long as the first card view layout exists in the recycler view. If it doesn't exists in the recycler view, and I try adding the second card view layout first by clicking on the button to add it a couple times, it will add it along with the first card view layout. Also, when trying to remove the card views from the layout they are not removing correctly. Here is what I have in my java code...

MainActivity.Java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addConverterCard = new ArrayList<>();

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerItemAdapter recyclerItemAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public TextView ftocConverterLabelBtn, ftokConverterLabelBtn;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_view);
        ftocConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_f_to_c_converter_label_btn);
        ftokConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_f_to_k_converter_label_btn);

ftocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    addConverterCard.add(new RecyclerItem());
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                    recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addConverterCard);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerItemAdapter);
                    recyclerItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ftokConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    addConverterCard.add(new RecyclerItem());
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
                    recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addConverterCard);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });
```

Adapter.Java

```
public static class RecyclerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerItemAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
        

        public ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerItemList;
        public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener recyclerItemListener;
        public List<String> converterType;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick (int position);
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            recyclerItemListener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener;
        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView convertResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;

            public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert);
                convertResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftc);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder2 extends RecyclerViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView convertResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;

            public RecyclerViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener2) {
                super(itemView, listener2);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert2);
                convertResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftk);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn2);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card2);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener2 != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener2.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return position % 2 * 2;
        }

        public RecyclerItemAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> rList) {
            recyclerItemList = rList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            switch (viewType) {
                case 0:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_celsius_converter_layout, parent, false);
                RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
                return recyclerViewHolder;

                case 2:
                    View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_kelvin_converter_layout, parent, false);
                    RecyclerViewHolder2 recyclerViewHolder2 = new RecyclerViewHolder2(v2, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
                    return recyclerViewHolder2;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                case 0: RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;
                RecyclerItem currentItem = recyclerItemList.get(position);
                final String[] result = new String[1];

                viewHolder.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}

                viewHolder.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        removeCard(viewHolder.getLayoutPosition());
                    }
                });

                break;

                case 2: RecyclerViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (RecyclerViewHolder2)holder;
                    RecyclerItem currentItem2 = recyclerItemList.get(position);
                    final String[] result2 = new String[1];

                    viewHolder2.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}

                    viewHolder2.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            removeCard(viewHolder2.getLayoutPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    break;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return recyclerItemList.size();
        }

        public void removeCard(int position) {
            recyclerItemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

    }

    public class RecyclerItem {

        public RecyclerItem() {

        }

    }
```

I appreciate your help!

Full Adapter Class

```
    public static class RecyclerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerItemAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {


        public ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerItemList;
        public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener recyclerItemListener;
        public List<String> converterType;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick (int position);
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            recyclerItemListener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener;
        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView convertResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;

            public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert);
                convertResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftc);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder2 extends RecyclerViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView convertResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;

            public RecyclerViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener2) {
                super(itemView, listener2);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert2);
                convertResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftk);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn2);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card2);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener2 != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener2.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return recyclerItemList.get(position).getType;
        }

        public RecyclerItemAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> rList) {
            recyclerItemList = rList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            switch (viewType) {
                case 0:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_celsius_converter_layout, parent, false);
                RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
                return recyclerViewHolder;

                case 1:
                    View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_kelvin_converter_layout, parent, false);
                    RecyclerViewHolder2 recyclerViewHolder2 = new RecyclerViewHolder2(v2, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
                    return recyclerViewHolder2;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                case 0: RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;
                RecyclerItem currentItem = recyclerItemList.get(position);
                final String[] result = new String[1];

                viewHolder.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String getIputFahValue = viewHolder.inputFahValueET.getText().toString();
                        NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
                        if (!getIputFahValue.isEmpty()) {
                            double d = Double.parseDouble(getIputFahValue);
                            double dd = d - 32;
                            double ddd = dd * 5;
                            double dddd = ddd / 9;
                            result[0] = Double.toString(dddd);

                            viewHolder.convertResult.setText(nf.format(dddd) + "°C");
                            viewHolder.convertResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            viewHolder.shortResult = nf.format(dddd) + "°C";
                            viewHolder.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + nf.format(dddd) + "°C";

                            if (result[0].contains(".0")) {
                                result[0] = result[0].replace(".0", "");
                                viewHolder.convertResult.setText(result[0] + "°C");
                                viewHolder.convertResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                viewHolder.shortResult = result[0] + "°C";
                                viewHolder.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + result[0] + "°C";
                            } else if (result[0].contains(".000")) {
                                result[0] = result[0].replace(".000", "");
                                viewHolder.convertResult.setText(result[0] + "°C");
                                viewHolder.convertResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                viewHolder.shortResult = result[0] + "°C";
                                viewHolder.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + result[0] + "°C";
                            }

                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Fahrenheit Value Field Cannot Be Blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.convertResult.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                        adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_file_copy_32);
                        adb.setTitle("Copy Result");
                        adb.setMessage("You can copy the result to your clipboard if you would like. Choose if you want the short or long result copied to your clipboard.\n\nExample of Short and Long Result:\nShort Result: 32°C\nLong Result: 0°F is 32°C");

                        adb.setPositiveButton("Short", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", holder.shortResult);
                                cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Result Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        adb.setNegativeButton("Long", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", holder.longResult);
                                cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Result Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                        adb.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            }
                        });

                        adb.create();
                        adb.show();

                        return false;
                    }
                });

                viewHolder.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        removeCard(viewHolder.ge);
                    }
                });

                break;

                case 2: RecyclerViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (RecyclerViewHolder2)holder;
                    RecyclerItem currentItem2 = recyclerItemList.get(position);
                    final String[] result2 = new String[1];

                    viewHolder2.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            String getIputFahValue = viewHolder2.inputFahValueET.getText().toString();
                            NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("0.000");
                            if (!getIputFahValue.isEmpty()) {
                                double d = Double.parseDouble(getIputFahValue);
                                double dd = d - 32;
                                double ddd = dd * 5;
                                double dddd = ddd / 9;
                                double ddddd = dddd + 273.15;
                                result2[0] = Double.toString(ddddd);

                                viewHolder2.convertResult.setText(nf.format(ddddd) + "°K");
                                viewHolder2.convertResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                viewHolder2.shortResult = nf.format(dddd) + "°K";
                                viewHolder2.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + nf.format(dddd) + "°K";

                                if (result2[0].contains(".0")) {
                                    result2[0] = result2[0].replace(".0", "");
                                    viewHolder2.convertResult.setText(result2[0] + "°K");
                                    viewHolder2.convertResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    viewHolder2.shortResult = result2[0] + "°K";
                                    viewHolder2.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + result2[0] + "°K";
                                } else if (result2[0].contains(".000")) {
                                    result2[0] = result2[0].replace(".000", "");
                                    viewHolder2.convertResult.setText(result2[0] + "°K");
                                    viewHolder2.convertResult.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    viewHolder2.shortResult = result2[0] + "°K";
                                    viewHolder2.longResult = getIputFahValue + "°F is " + result2[0] + "°K";
                                }

                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Fahrenheit Value Field Cannot Be Blank!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder2.convertResult.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                            adb.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_file_copy_32);
                            adb.setTitle("Copy Result");
                            adb.setMessage("You can copy the result to your clipboard if you would like. Choose if you want the short or long result copied to your clipboard.\n\nExample of Short and Long Result:\nShort Result: 283.15°K\nLong Result: 50°F is 283.15°K");

                            adb.setPositiveButton("Short", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", holder.shortResult);
                                    cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Result Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                            adb.setNegativeButton("Long", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                    ClipboardManager cbm = (ClipboardManager) view.getContext().getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                                    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Copy", holder.longResult);
                                    cbm.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Result Copied!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });

                            adb.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                }
                            });

                            adb.create();
                            adb.show();

                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    viewHolder2.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            removeCard(viewHolder2.getLayoutPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    break;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return recyclerItemList.size();
        }

        public void removeCard(int position) {
            recyclerItemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

    }

    public static class RecyclerItem {
        public int getType;
        int type;

        public RecyclerItem(int mType) {
            this.getType = mType;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type();
        }

        private int type() {
            return type;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking at your code - you are creating a new Adapter with a single element on every button click. This means the RecyclerView will always have a single element. The first element will always be of type RecyclerViewHolder because its position is 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there's some mistakes I suspect so I will try and suggest some things maybe it fixes your code behavior.

- in removing the card, consider using `holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()` instead of `viewHolder.getLayoutPosition()` or `getAdapterPosition`.
- on adding any card, stop creating a new Adapter and LayoutManager over and over again, this components should be created once for any RecylcerView, just keep a reference to only the first old created adapter as a global variable, add the new card to the data ArrayList that the old adapter has reference to, use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` on the old adapter reference that you're keeping as global variable.
- I don't know how the viewType algorithm works, but if the options from add button decide which one you want, store an index to which card you want in the **RecyclerItem** object itself and in `getItemViewType` that you're overriding get the item at the required position and return its stored type rather than this strange position calculation (position%2*2).
  by doing that make switch cases according to the integer values that you will be storing in `ftoc/ftok/...etcConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener`.
  that would be a solution that it doesn't add or delete the right type of card in correspondence to your add/delete choices since your viewType algorithm will return value based on just the position not your choice.
- anytime I used `setHasFixedSize(true)` it caused me trouble, so if you don't have a good reason to be using this, I suggest that you delete/comment its line of code completely

---

### Update

your code should be looking like this :

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<RecyclerItem> addConverterCard ;

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerItemAdapter recyclerItemAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public TextView ftocConverterLabelBtn, ftokConverterLabelBtn;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_item_view);
        ftocConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_f_to_c_converter_label_btn);
        ftokConverterLabelBtn = findViewById(R.id.add_f_to_k_converter_label_btn);
addConverterCard = new ArrayList<>();
recyclerItemAdapter = new RecyclerItemAdapter(addConverterCard);
layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerItemAdapter);
ftocConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    addConverterCard.add(new RecyclerItem(0));
                    recyclerItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });

        ftokConverterLabelBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (clicked) {
                    addConverterCard.add(new RecyclerItem(1));
                    recyclerItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    closeActionButton();
                }
            }
        });
```

**Adapter code**

```
public static class RecyclerItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerItemAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {
        

        public ArrayList<RecyclerItem> recyclerItemList;
        public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener recyclerItemListener;
        public List<String> converterType;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick (int position);
        }

        public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
            recyclerItemListener = (AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) listener;
        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView convertResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;

            public RecyclerViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert);
                convertResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftc);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        public static class RecyclerViewHolder2 extends RecyclerViewHolder {

            EditText inputFahValueET;
            TextView convertResult;
            ImageView tempIconAndConvertBtn;
            ImageView deleteCardBtn;
            String shortResult, longResult;

            public RecyclerViewHolder2(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener2) {
                super(itemView, listener2);

                inputFahValueET = itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_fahrenheit_value_to_convert2);
                convertResult = itemView.findViewById(R.id.output_result_ftk);
                tempIconAndConvertBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.temp_icon_convert_btn2);
                deleteCardBtn = itemView.findViewById(R.id.remove_card2);

                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        if (listener2 != null) {
                            int position = getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
                            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                                listener2.onItemClick(position);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return recyclerItemList.get(position).getType();
        }

        public RecyclerItemAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerItem> rList) {
            recyclerItemList = rList;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            switch (viewType) {
                case 0:
                View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_celsius_converter_layout, parent, false);
                RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder = new RecyclerViewHolder(v, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
                return recyclerViewHolder;

                case 1:
                    View v2 = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.fahrenheit_to_kelvin_converter_layout, parent, false);
                    RecyclerViewHolder2 recyclerViewHolder2 = new RecyclerViewHolder2(v2, (OnItemClickListener) recyclerItemListener);
                    return recyclerViewHolder2;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
            switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
                case 0: RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder = (RecyclerViewHolder) holder;
                RecyclerItem currentItem = recyclerItemList.get(position);
                final String[] result = new String[1];

                viewHolder.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...});

                viewHolder.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        removeCard(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                    }
                });

                break;

                case 1: RecyclerViewHolder2 viewHolder2 = (RecyclerViewHolder2)holder;
                    RecyclerItem currentItem2 = recyclerItemList.get(position);
                    final String[] result2 = new String[1];

                    viewHolder2.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...});

                    viewHolder2.deleteCardBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            removeCard(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                        }
                    });

                    break;

            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return recyclerItemList.size();
        }

        public void removeCard(int position) {
            recyclerItemList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }

    public class RecyclerItem {
        int type ;
        public RecyclerItem(int m_type) {
        this.type = m_type ;
        }
        public int getType(){
            return type;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to add some things to the public class RecyclerItem at the bottom of the adapter class because I was getting a red line under type. The return type. It wanted me to add a couple things. public int getType above the (int type), and private int type(){return type}; After those were added the red line went away, and it's adding the cards like I want. However, when it comes to removing the cards, getAbsoluteAdapterPosition doesn't exist in the menu when I start typing removeCard(holder.) the list that comes up here doesn't list it. I wonder why?

Comment: well sorry about the getType incident as I don't really put the code in a real class and just right here instantly, my bad but good thing you've managed your way through. regarding the problem with holder that it doesn't have the method just give me some minutes/time I will try to figure what's wrong and get back to ya :\

Comment: If I just type it in like this removeCard(holder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition); the getAbsoluteAdaptetPosition turns red like it doesn't know what it is. The choices in the menu are: getLayoutPosition(), getAdapterPosition(), getOldPosition(), getPosition() (depreciated), getItemViewType(), getItemId(), and getClass()

Comment: it looks good to me, did you forget to close the brackets properly on the line above it `viewHolder.tempIconAndConvertBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {...}` ?, it seems it misses `);`.

Comment: Nope, it's closed properly.

Comment: yes all those seems to belong to **RecyclerView.ViewHolder** naturally which is weird that you don't see `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition` between them. - https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder#getAbsoluteAdapterPosition()

Comment: can you edit your question to include the full new Adapter code ? maybe it's an import or Object Type mistake as my code doesn't show any error and acts normally.

Comment: Ok there you go.

Comment: I swear it exist for me see the photo - https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWLhW.png - the only thing I have changed is that I removed the `static` identifier from the adapter,RecyclerViewHolder,RecyclerViewHolder2 and RecyclerItem because I didn't understand why do you use static.

Comment: in this case I don't know how to help, you can try using `getLayoutPosition` or `getBindingAdapterPosition`  if you see them but I didn't try them myself before so I can't guarantee the returned values. avoid `getAdapterPosition` and `getPosition` as they're deprecated.

Comment: if you still having some problems with your code then consider removing that my answer satsify your question and wait others to solve it or maybe start a new question see how it goes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237110/discussion-between-omar-shawky-and-lllcoderlll).

Comment: Hmm. I wonder if it's because I am missing a dependency or a certain update or platform tools? I have the SDKCompiled at api 30 with build tools also at 30. MinSDKVersion is api 23.

Comment: if `getAbsoluteAdapterPosition` works in some places and doesn't work in others, then no I don't think that's the case. if it doesn't work at all, then yes maybe you got an old dependency, check in your build.gradle(Module:app) if you have the last version of RecyclerView, mine is `implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1"`.

Comment: I checked the build.gradle and I didn't have the recyclerview dependency in there. It was an oversight. Anyways, I added it, synced it, and now I have getAbsoluteAdapterPosition finally! I changed it to that, and now it's removing correctly. Everything now is working as it should. Thanks for all your help again man! I really appreciate it!

Comment: no problem and Good Luck in completing your app.